# Why am I getting ValueError: I/O operation on closed file when trying to write to a .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

'' I am ready file 'Mock_data.csv' that contain Fields: first_name, last_name, email and is trying to
write each line of with file to a new file called 'New_Mock_data.csv' with fields: first_name, last_name.
On line 'csv_writer.writerow(line)' I get error 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.' What am I going wrong?''

```
import csv

with open('Mock_data.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('New_Mock_data.csv','w') as new_csv_file:
        field_names = ['first_name','last_name']
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_csv_file,fieldnames = field_names,delimiter = '\t')
        csv_writer.writeheader()  # write the header record

    for line in csv_reader:
        del line['email']
        print(line)
        csv_writer.writerow(line) # write the line
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are out of the `with` scope, the file is automatically closed. So you need to change indentation of the for loop in this way:

```
import csv

with open('Mock_data.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('New_Mock_data.csv','w') as new_csv_file:
        field_names = ['first_name','last_name']
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_csv_file,fieldnames = field_names,delimiter = '\t')
        csv_writer.writeheader()  # write the header record

        for line in csv_reader:
            del line['email']
            print(line)
            csv_writer.writerow(line) # write the line
```

Comment: Thanks Aeglas - much appreciated. I did you change your suggested and it is working fine.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you accept the answer then? Thank you.